# Autoresizing Across Multiple Devices?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uikit, xcode8

Creating an app to use all forms of iPad that support iOS-10
I use Xcode 8.2.1 and Objective-C.

The issue I am faced with, is when I design my Storyboard and place the controls and their constraints in place for a specific iPad model, as soon as I simulate with a different iPad model, I lose the existing control layout.

The application only uses **Landscape**.

Are there useful guides available that will help be with the Autoresizing as I go from one iPad model to the next?

Pete

Comment: are you seeing a difference between iPad Pro and the rest? Because every single iPad before the Pro had a screen resolution of 1024 x 768. More details on the models here would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks Dan, Yes mate, I am using the iPad Pro 12.9" as the design platform.

Even going to iPad Pro 9.7" will change the way it looks. 

I was under the impression that regardless what model I use, it will automatically readjust to suit the screen resolution.

Comment: Read about Autolayout. Plenty of good examples at Apple and other places online. My only hint to you would be to design for the smaller iPads first, and then scale up. No empirical evidence for this, just experience talking.